# Posts by admin on the top from all the post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am retrieving some post and to show post on first come first basic. Now I want to show those post on the top which are posted by admin and the rest post by non admin will come after admin posts.

the code I am using in php is:

```
$tit = get_the_title();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>'contribute',
        'numberposts' => 100,
        'meta_key' => 'portfolio',
        'meta_value' => $tit ,
    );
    $slides = get_posts($args);
    ?>
     <ul id="myList">
     <?php foreach($slides as $post) : setup_postdata($post);   ?>

           <li>the post will go here</li>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To display posts from admin first and then from non-admin, you have to call get_posts twice.

Once with :-

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' =>'contribute',
        'numberposts' => 100,
        'meta_key' => 'portfolio',
        'meta_value' => $tit ,
        'author' => '123' // where 123 is ID of your admin author
    );
```

The other will be :-

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' =>'contribute',
        'numberposts' => 100,
        'meta_key' => 'portfolio',
        'meta_value' => $tit ,
        'author' => '-123' // display posts except admin author
    );
```

Comment: any other method besides calling two get_posts because I have a lot of data inside foreach section mean too much.. that will overload my page and any error will be out of coverage.

Comment: you can use wp_query_reset() after each get_posts

Comment: I think I have found solution of my porblem by adding order by=> administrator. with single get_post.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `author` method to your array:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' =>'contribute',
    'numberposts' => 100,
    'meta_key' => 'portfolio',
    'meta_value' => $tit,
    'author_name' => 'Administrator' //add this, change Administrator to your name
);
```

Comment: this will give me posts only by administrator, Am I right? But I want all the posts I have including admin and non admin post where admin posts will be on top